# DataGridView DataBinding Columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataTable that contains two Columns :-

```
 UserID | UserName
 ----------------- 
 UserA  | Fredd Bloggs 
 UserB  | John West
```

This will be the datasource for my `DatagridView`.

What I then Want to do is create a new `DataGridComboBoxColumn` that will allow the user to select from the dropdownlist, all of the different `UserName's` in the table. I

I can do this by setting the datasource for the `ComboBox` to the `DataTable` and setting the `DataPropertyName` to `UserName`.

But where I'm stuck in thought, is on the User selecting a new `UserName`. the `UserID` Column Value changing to reflect the newly selected `UserName`.

Does anyone know the method for doing this.

This is just a test at present, but I will need to use it in a project quite heavily.

Comment: for a normal combobox you'd use the `SelectedItemChanged()` or `SelectedValueChanged()` methods. (or ones similiar to that). I am not sure if you could use this in a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` but might be worth a try.

Comment: No, It does'nt Have those Event Handles.